# How to get all keys from a given 3D map value?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I have a 3D map container declared as follows:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, CGridItem*> > > m_3DGridItems;
```

Suppose I have a CGridItem object pointer value, how can I get all the three map key strings in an efficient way? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. I used three clumsy loopings to do that. Any simple and clear way?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do you really need such a clumsy container ?

It would be much easier to have a `Key` structure:

```
struct Key {
  std::string x;
  std::string y;
  std::string z;
};
```

And then define an ordering on `Key`:

```
bool operator<(Key const& left, Key const& right) {
  if (left.x < right.x) { return true; }
  if (left.x > right.x) { return false; }

  if (left.y < right.y) { return true; }
  if (left.y > right.y) { return false; }

  return left.z < right.z;
}
```

Then you can have a much easier structure to manipulate:

```
std::map<Key, GridItem*>
```

If you need to map both ways, check out [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) which maintains a two-ways mapping `Key <-> GridItem*` (so you don't have to sync two structures yourself).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use iterator to get all key/value in a map. When the value is a map too, you can get the key/values the same way ...

Answer (score 0):

First thing: if you are primarily making look-ups like that, this data-structure is definitely **not** the best performing alternative.

I don't see any other way than to make three nested for loops, since the map is laid out to make look-ups by key and not by value. It would look something like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, CGridItem*> > >:iterator it1;
CGridItem* obj = ...;
for(it1 = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it1)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, CGridItem*> > it2;
    for(it2 = it1->second.begin(); it2 != it->second.end(); ++it2)
    {
        std::map<std::string, CGridItem*> it3;
        for(it3 = it2->second.begin(); it3 != it2->second.end(); ++it3)
        {
            if(it3->second == obj) {
                /*found it!*/
                /* your 3 strings are in it1->first, it2->first, it3->first */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I propose the following data structure:

```
std::map<CGridItem*, std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string> > mymap;
```

This maps your `CGridItem` object to 3 strings. Note: the `std::tuple` may not be available when you are not using c++11, but it is available in the [boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html).

Comment: Constantinius: Thank you! I think I must define another 3D map like this: std::map<CGridItem*, std:map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string> > > myAnotheMap;

Comment: How about using a different data structure? I'll update my answer, just a sec.

Comment: Also do not forget, that initially he could have same `CGridItem`s for different tuples of string, which isn't possible anymore if you reverse the key-value relation in the new data structure.